# js web workers and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, web-worker

I'm trying to create a `cron` file in PHP. The application I've created has around 30 active users. I want each user to run a JavaScript web-worker periodically in the background which invokes a PHP file (via ajax/xmlhttprequest) that calls a PHP file to run.

Do JavaScript Web-Workers, when calling a PHP file via the Worker, block the main PHP requests from being executed, since they come from the same browser?

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question ? What does the question have to do with `cron` ?

Comment: you're absolutely right! i've changed it now..

Comment: Still unclear : the text looks like a solution looking for a problem to solve. What are you trying to solve ?

Comment: No, AJAX does not block the page requests. However, if you make an AJAX call, because it does not block, you can interrupt it with a PHP request before it finishes, too - say by reloading the page. The reason for this is that PHP requests themselves are "full-page" requests - they're asking the server for a document to place at a URL; whereas Ajax was created to work around this by letting you make small data requests without having to reload the entire document/page. Hope that helps!

Comment: The browser can't run two PHP scripts at the same time. If I want to run a certain PHP script to do various processing, the next request will be queued. I was wondering if using a javascript worker that two PHP could be run simultaneous.

Comment: Aaah, I see your updates to your question. I think the asnwer is no, you cannot run two simultaneous page requests on the same page. But the closest thing I know of to what you seem to want -- threaded JavaScript -- is HTML 5 Web Workers, but I'm personally unfamiliar with using them atm.

Comment: What blocking of php requests are you talking of? A browser does limit the number of concurrent connections to one domain (often six). On the other hand, it is possible that a session on the server keeps concurrent request from the same session from executing in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you'll need to put an state to close the execution while a file is executing. Use callbacks on Workers to filter execution by status (can be [HTTPs status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)) and close the socket listener while some callback isn't triggered or some state (some storage or variable) isn't filled by certain value.

Take the example from [MDN page about Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers):

example.html: (the main page):

```
var myWorker = new Worker('my_task.js');

myWorker.onmessage = function(oEvent) {
  //take current status from the worker from oEvent
  status = oEvent.status;
  console.log('Worker said : ' + oEvent.status);
};
//if ok, send an order to continue receiving php calls
if (status == 200)
  //or other function
  myWorker.postMessage('someorder');
```

my_task.js (the worker):

```
postMessage("Worker listening");

onmessage = function(oEvent) {
  //if status is not ok, worker is busy and can't do anything
  if (status != 200)
     postMessage('Hi ' + oEvent.data);
};
```

You were so general that it's the only thing that came within my mind to solve your problem.